# Не удается решить задачу с рекурсией

Tags: c, рекурсия

Не получается вычислить по формуле с помощью рекурсии. Формула такая: a1+a1*a2+a1*a2*a3 и так далее. Создаю массив, заполняю его рандомными числами, отображаю его на экране. И затем вызываю функцию, которая должна это все вычислить. Но у меня лишь получилось, чтоб эти числа умножались. А как сделать чтоб они еще и складывались?

Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ex1(int *, int,int,int);

int main()
{
    time_t t; srand(time(&t));

    int n=5; //printf("Размер массива: "); scanf("%d",&n);
    int *parr = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
        *(parr+i) = rand()%2+1;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
        printf("%3i", *(parr+i));
    }
    int i=1,g=0;
    printf("\n");
    int out = ex1(parr,n,i,g);
    printf("Out = %d",out);

    delete [] parr;
    return 0;
}

int ex1(int *arr, int n,int i, int g){
    return n!=1 ? *(arr+g)*ex1(arr,n-1,i,g+1): i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку ваша формула суммы преобразуется так `a1 + a1*a2 + a1*a2*a3 = a1 * (1 + a2 * (1 + a3**...)`, то и функция должна выглядеть как-то так

```
int ex2(int *arr, int n, int g)
{
    return (g == n) ? 0 : (arr[g] * (1 + ex2(arr, n, g + 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Никакой у вас не С++, а чистый С.

А сделать можно, например, добавив лишний параметр - последнее произведение (первое, что пришло в голову, не скажу, что лучший вариант...)

```
int sum(int * arr, int n, int * prod)
{
    if (n == 0) { *prod = arr[0]; return arr[0]; }
    int s = sum(arr,n-1,prod);
    *prod *= arr[n];
    return s + *prod;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 4, 3, 1};
    int prod;
    printf("%d\n", sum(arr,4,&prod));

}
```

Comment: Да, точно. извиняюсь. Просто препод говорит, чтоб на `C` писать